# ¿Como puedo guardar datos en js sin que se piedan cuando la pagina se recargue? ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, google-chrome, firefox

Estoy creando una aplicación pero necesito que los objetos que estan dentro de un array no se pierdan si se recarga la pagina, no se si es posible mediante un servicio de angular, o mediante alguna función.

Gracias y Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías trabajar con [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (JS-Nativo):

```
localStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan');
```

O usar un package para angular, ej:

- `angularjs`: [angular-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage)
- `angular`: [angular-localstorage4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-localstorage4)